# the right technology for making a mindmap app on android with react native

Tags: android, react-native, canvas, frameworks, mindmap

currently I am creating a multi platform mindmap application. The web version of my software is completed. To complete the web version application I use:
-React
-Node j's
-Mongodb
-Konva
Now I want to attack the second part of my quest: the mobile application. For that I want to use:
-React Native
-Node js
-MongoDB

- Missing technology (Something to draw mindmap)

I have tried a lot of canvas framework with react native, but there are not good enough to build what I want. Can some tell me a good framework like konava but for reacting native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the core, React Native is not designed for graphics-intensive application, Team at Shopify are sponsoring William Candillon and Christian Falch to bring Skia 2D graphic Library - https://skia.org/ to React Native.

The project is still in early-stage but it's open opportunity in this space -  https://github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia